# The silent parrot

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A woman wants to buy a parrot. The shopkeeper says "This parrot, I assure you, will repeat every word it hears." After 3 months of training, the parrot didn't utter a single word.

Assuming the shopkeeper was telling the truth, why did the parrot not talk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be simplifying it, but it seems like:

> training does not imply speaking, so the parrot just never heard a word for the 3 months because no words were spoken to it

or similarly:

> the parrot is deaf

Answer (score 5):

answer 1

> The parrot is dead, and therefore cannot hear anything

answer 2

> the parrot is deaf and therefore cannot hear anything

answer 3

> the woman is a mute, so the parrot does not hear anything

Comment: I think you've covered them all.. except maybe the "this parrot" referred to by the shopkeeper is not the parrot the woman ended up with in the end..

Comment: Other possibilities: 1. The parrot has a for-month delay between hearing a word and repeating it. 2. The shopkeeper did, in fact, assure the woman that the parrot would repeat everything, and thus was telling the truth when he said that he was assuring her of that. 3. The parrot repeated the words in sign language (it's very talented). 4. The parrot repeated the words during training (the question says "After 3 months of training, the parrot didn't utter a single word.", not "After 3 months of training, the parrot *hadn't uttered* a single word.

Answer (score 2):

A semantics, silly, solution. The parrot had already heard and repeated all the words used in the training.

Comment: So it only repeats a word once?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps

> that is... the parrot has no memory.Irrespective of how many months training it received, as it repeats only the words it hears, after 3 months of training nothing is 'spoken' to it and hence it remains silent.